# mySQL: LEFT JOIN where joining needs to be done on different type of data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 my tables with data and 2 "not mine" tables (in ReferenceDB) where thing ID can be mapped to its name.

One of mine tables is orders with following important columns: `charName, stationID, typeID, bid.`

Another table has following important columns: `transactionDateTime, stationID, typeID, person, transactionType`

I started my head braking with idea how to find orders that doesn't have any records for them lately (e.g. given amount of days). But for beginning I set me a task just to find orders that has no records for them at all. For that I figured out `LEFT JOIN` see biggest query below.

An order for me is a combination of `charName/persone` + `stationID` + `typeID` + `transactionType/bid` so if actually one of those four changes it is different order then.

Problem is that transactionType can be "yes" or "no" and bid is 0 or not 0. So I cant or **DON'T KNOW HOW** to `JOIN ON` different data types. So logically I'd like to join on 4 columns like:

```
FROM ordersTable LEFT JOIN recordsTable ON ordersTable.typeID = recordsTable.typeID 
AND ordersTable.stationID = recordsTable.stationID 
AND ordersTable.charName = recordsTable.person 
AND ordersTable.bid = recordsTable.transactionType
```

Clearly last string of above wouldn't work cause of different data types.
So for a moment I thought that I can do such query twice for *bid=0 with transactionType="yes"* and second time for *bid != 0 and transactionType = "no"* **see my query below** for *0/"yes"* combination. But seems it doesn't works exactly as I'd like it to. because `AND ordersTable.bid IN (0) AND recordsTable.transactionType="yes"` in JOIN ON doesn't sem do anything. (As I do get results where bid=1)

```
SELECT invTypes.typeName, stastations.stationName, main.* FROM referenceDB.invTypes, referenceDB.stastations, (
SELECT ordersTable.charName, ordersTable.stationID, ordersTable.typeID, ordersTable.bid, ordersTable.orderState, ordersTable.volRemaining
FROM ordersTable LEFT JOIN recordsTable ON ordersTable.typeID = recordsTable.typeID 
AND ordersTable.stationID = recordsTable.stationID 
AND ordersTable.charName = recordsTable.person 
AND ordersTable.bid IN (0) AND recordsTable.transactionType="yes" 
WHERE recordsTable.typeID IS NULL 
AND ordersTable.orderState IN (0) ) as main
WHERE stastations.stationID = main.stationID AND invTypes.typeID = main.typeID;
```

**Questions:**
Is it possible to tell mySQL to treat "yes" as 0 or vise versa? If yes how do I do it in my query? If no what would be my work around (to find orders that doesn't have records related to them)?

And possibly some one can suggset a query that will find orders that didn't have records within given amount of days?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use the explicit comparisons:

```
((ordersTable.bid = 0 and recordsTable.transactionType = 'No') or
 (ordersTable.bid = 1 and recordsTable.transactionType = 'Yes')
)
```

Another would be to use a `case` statement:

```
(case when recordsTable.transactionType = 'No' then 0 else 1 end) = ordersTable.bid
```

Comment: Thank you it works! I think performance isn't the issue for me now but just out of curiosity and possible for future reference. Is there difference from performance point of view in above mentioned two methods?

Comment: In my case LEFT JOIN +condition WHERE recordsTable.typeID IS NULL does finds for me orders that had no transactions. What approach I should use if I want to find orders that has transactions where some condition about transactions is TRUE?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT invTypes.typeName, stastations.stationName, main.* FROM referenceDB.invTypes, referenceDB.stastations, (
SELECT ordersTable.charName, ordersTable.stationID, ordersTable.typeID, ordersTable.bid, ordersTable.orderState, ordersTable.volRemaining
FROM ordersTable LEFT JOIN recordsTable ON ordersTable.typeID = recordsTable.typeID 
AND ordersTable.stationID = recordsTable.stationID 
AND ordersTable.charName = recordsTable.person 
AND ((ordersTable.bid = 0 AND recordsTable.transactionType = 'yes') OR
    (ordersTable.bid != 0 AND recordsTable.transactionType = 'no')) 
WHERE recordsTable.typeID IS NULL 
AND ordersTable.orderState IN (0) ) as main
WHERE stastations.stationID = main.stationID AND invTypes.typeID = main.typeID;
```